# Нужны советы по созданию сайта

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, angular

Хочу написать сайт наподобии **радио**: у меня есть плейлист, который я воспроизвожу, а также могу его редактировать: добавлять, удалять или переключать треки (Иными словами - имею к нему **полный доступ**.). Юзеры просто слушают воспроизводимую музыку, соответственно, не имея доступа к редактированию плейлиста. Возникли следующие вопросы:

1. Как и где лучше хранить треки?
2. Как их воспроизводить?
3. Можно ли написать это на Django в связке с Angular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Музыку надо застримить в сеть для начала. Тут выбор чаще всего падает на icecast. Но можно обойтись и VLC+nginx - тогда получится интерактивное управление вместо "админки".

Воспроизводить: плеер на основе html5 или flash.

Джанго тут не нужна - просто статичная странички или SPA. Ангуляр подойдет.

Питон не понадобится скорее всего.